# facebook search code or friends list display

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was using user_friends tag to display a user's facebooks friends. However, with the new update it will only show friends who have used the app before (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends)

The only information I want to get from the API is the friend's names. Is there a way to get and display these names without going through the app approval process.

Alternatively, Is there a way I can add something like the facebook search, where a user can start typing out a name and have facebook bring up search results. Again the only thing I need are the names. (I don't need friends' emails, profile info etc)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with any approval, for just listing the names of your friends there is no possible way anymore. You don´t need to get `user_friends` approved (it is approved by default), but it will only show the friends who authorized your App too, as you already found out.

About searching users, please take a look at the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search